# Does putting less number of curly braces really helps?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-construction, clr

What if do not use a curly braces after an if statement. Like :-

```
if(SomeCondition())
    return true;
```

Instead of

```
if(SomeCondition())
{
  return true;
}
```

Does it really help the compiler be it in terms of compilation time, better IL code generation, accquires less space or any other aspect (which at this point I am really not able to think of) ? Would like to know does it really help or is it just about code readability ?

Comment: They are the same. They both generate same `IL` code.

Comment: they are exactly the same, and curly braces are **required** unless your conditional result is only one statement long, so it's not common to skip them.

Comment: `return SomeCondition();` is the same (in sence of IL code) but easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do the same. 
The `MSIL` code will be almost the same in both cases if your'e in debug mode(Thanks Dirk).
In release mode the `MSIL` will be the same.

Here's a linqpad example(debug mode):

Example1:
C#:

```
void Main()
{
    bool a = true;
    int i;
    if(a)
     i = 17;  
}
```

IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  stloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_0008:  ldloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_0009:  brtrue.s    IL_000E
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.s    11 
IL_000D:  stloc.1     // i
```

Example2:

C#:

```
void Main()
{
    bool a = true;
    int i;
    if(a)
    {
     i = 17;  
    }
}
```

IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  stloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_0008:  ldloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_0009:  brtrue.s    IL_0010
IL_000B:  nop         
IL_000C:  ldc.i4.s    11 
IL_000E:  stloc.1     // i
```

Comment: The difference is because you probably used debug mode for compilation. In release mode the `nop` won't be emitted.

Comment: Fun part: Size of MSIL code is runtime factor, not the compilation time factor. Using release with braces should be longer in terms of cpu cycles needed to create the IL as lexer parses extra braces and release optimization might (if NOP are emitted) need to compress extra instructions (the NOPs)

Comment: @Samuel The NOPs are inserted to help with debugging (most notably, setting breakpoints to block starts and Edit & Continue). They're not added in release build at all. And of course, if your tweaks in compilation times get down to empty bracers, you're probably too deep already.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all in the generated code, at least not in release mode. In debug mode there might be some more `nop` instructions added, so that there is at least one instruction per line so that you can single step through the lines when you debug the code.

There is naturally a difference in compilation time, as the codes aren't identical. However, that difference is so small that you would need to have millions of lines of code before you can even notice the difference.

You should use the one that makes the code easier to maintain. If your code style causes you to do a mistake, just one mistake will take longer to fix than the total time that you could ever save in compilation.

---

Personally I prefer to always have the brackets there, even if there is a single statement in the code block. It's easier to read the code if it follows a single pattern instead of two different patterns depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you are right as the lexer part of the tool chain does not need to parse those additional tokens but the difference is a couple of CPU cycles, so you won't notice this and I suggest to always use braces.

Edit: As others pointed out: The code will be the same. If you read the grammar specification for C# (and for some other languages like C, C++, Java) then you will see that if condition is followed by a `statement`, not by several statements. In order to be able to write several statements for the if condition you will need the curly braces.
You are forced to use the braces when you will additionally log something or do something before the return.

For your situation the MSIL code IMHO `may` look the same, but this is not guaranteed. As the compiler is free to add `NOP` IL-commands whenever the compiler feels so. The semantic of your code however won't change.

Long story short: Your samples are semantically equivalent.

Comment: Why do you suggest to always use braces? I don't, and I sincerely think in scenarios such as the one posted by the OP, eliding the braces makes it more readable.

Comment: Ok, If possible kindly upvote my question! as I guess the question really makes sense !

Comment: Also, omitting the braces while stacking multiple `using` statements *greatly!* helps with readibility.

Comment: I agree with @dcastro that for very simple statements it's usually more readable to omit the braces (because they are really just noise). However the reason some people use them always is in case someone else adds some code to the `if` part and forgets to add the curly braces... but if they forget that, there's probably a whole load more to worry about. ;)

Comment: As my context is rather C++ and there is a coding guide for that MISRA C 14.9 and MISRA C++ 6-4-1. We also have experienced some nasty code where statements without braces were extended without adding the braces resulted in `odd` code :) (and it was just my suggestion, which is of course debatable)

Answer (score 0):

They are both equivalent in terms of compilation time.  It really comes down to a question of personal preference.  Generally I like to include the braces for everything except return statements i.e. 
 
`if(condition)
{
  do something
}
else return x;`